# Module installed in virtual environment, yet my program raises a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows

I'm struggling to understand what just might be happening here:

```
(bvBot_env) C:\Users\You_A\>python -c "import ujson"

(bvBot_env) C:\Users\You_A\>main.bat
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\You_A\ line 9, in <module>
    import ujson as json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

The main python version on my os is 3.6. The version in my venv is 3.5.2. `ujson` is not installed version 3.6.

**EDIT**(contents of .bat file):

```
@py.exe C:\Users\You_A\Desktop\VirtualEnvironments\bvBot_env\bvBot\bvBot\main.py %*
@pause
```

**EDIT**
The problem resides with the batch file.
This avoids the `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
>python main.py
```

Comment: What's the content of your `.bat` file?

Comment: added info to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely not activating the python interpreter from the virtual environment.

What you have to do is

```
path\to\virtual\environment\python.exe path\to\script\main.py
```

The two paths may be the same, but calling the right `python.exe` is crucial.